# insert variable to mysql database as utf-8

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I have some value in other language and i want to use utf-8 for this value.for now i use this code for store variable in database.

```
<?php
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO user (fname , lname) VALUES (? , ? ) ");
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$fname,$lname);
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

I set collation for fname and lname column to utf-8.but i do not know how to modify database connection for insert variable as utf-8.I set collation of user table as utf-8.

Comment: have you put utf8 headers in your php file?

Comment: Have you tried what I posted ?

Comment: @adib16 `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` on top of your file

Comment: @cryptivous yes thank you for that.but i think i must try both of your  answer and the above comment.otherwise i must put uft8 header in php file and $mysqli->set_charset("utf8") .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); // at the top of the file

$mysqli->set_charset("utf8"); // before the query
```

[Set Charset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php), [Header](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)